# Lambda doesn't translate into Method Reference

Tags: java, android, lambda, rx-java, method-reference

Android Studio informs me that the following Lambda can be converted into a Method Reference:

```
        result -> result.getBleDevice()
```

But when I try, I get an error:

```
        RxBleScanResult::getBleDevice
```

The `result` parameter is of type `RxBleScanResult`, but I get the error "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". The code resides in a static method, but `result` is an object instance, in the class that defines the `getBleDevice()` method.

I've tried to understand the discussion of "reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type" but I don't see why this won't work, when the Lambda version is acceptable.

Update: here's the entire method (see the last 2 lines):

```
static Observable<RxBleDevice> getScanObservable( UUID serviceUUID ) {
    return GlucometerApplication.getRxBleClient()
            .scanBleDevices(
                    new ScanSettings.Builder()
                            .setScanMode( SCAN_MODE )
                            //.setMatchMode( MATCH_MODE )
                            .build(),
                    new ScanFilter.Builder()
                            .setServiceUuid( new ParcelUuid( serviceUUID ) )
                            .build()
            )
            //.map( result -> result.getBleDevice() )
            .map( RxBleScanResult::getBleDevice )
            ;
}
```

Comment: How is `getBleDevice` defined?

Comment: `scanBleDevices` emits `RxBleScanResult` objects. These have an instance method `public RxBleDevice getBleDevice()`

Comment: That `scanBleDevices` method [returns](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/fbd41758ed48e82f0a2d6b13ed066cea963c72b2/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble/RxBleClient.java#L120) `ScanResult`, not `RxBleScanResult`.

Comment: Bingo! @akarnokd! WTH, I have used that library quite a bit and I don't remember a separate type of ScanResult.